# Visual Studio Mac Floating Tab

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I have for error get the "errors" tab in my visual studio for Mac as a floating windows, and can't find the way to put it again inside the main window.

Does any one know how to put it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Close the window and go to Window > Reset window layout (or something of that sort).